# Items added to my custom list have the local scope

Tags: c#

I've created custom list:

```
public class BList : IEnumerable<Position>
{
        private List<Position> positions = new List<BPosition>();
        public void Add(Position p)
        { this.positions.Add(p); }
        ...
}
```

Than this list is member of the class Invoice:

```
public class Invoice : Record
{
        public BList Positions = null;
        public Invoice()
            : base()
        {
            Init();
            this.Positions = new BList(this);
        }
        ...
}
```

Now  in form constructor I populate collection of the Invoices and add positions to BList:

```
foreach(Invoice invoice in this.invoices)
{
    // Load position for current invoice from the database
    List<Position> positionsTmp = new List<Position>();
    DB.LoadRecordset(positionsTmp, "id_invoice=3");
    // and add to invoice positions items
    positionsTmp.ToList().ForEach(p => invoice.Positions.Add(p));
}
```

List of the positions in each invoice is populated correctly.
But when I use list this.invoices in other functions in this same class each invoice has Position list empty (Count = 0). It looks like positions are added localy and when application leaves the constructor all previously added positions do BList are cleared.
How I can populate BList for each invoice to they was available in entire class ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is confusing. What I think is the `Invoice` class constructor is named `Position`. And it references `this.Position`, when I think it needs to access `this.Positions`. And the `ForEach` in your constructor calls `invoice.Position.Add`, when I think it needs to be `invoice.Positions.Add`. Please clean up your code so that I can make sense of it.

Comment: So you're saying that in your `foreach` loop, the return value of `invoice.Positions.Count()` is non-zero, but at some later point in the code, the value is zero? If that's the case, then something else is clearing the list.

Comment: Yes in constructor invoice.Positions.Count is 1 and then in the same class when dataGridView selectionChanged event is fired invoice.Positions.Count is zero. BList cannot be clearing because it doesn't have function to clear items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name of your class is "Invoice", then the constructor must be called "Invoice" as well.

In the constructor of BList (I assume) you are intializing a local list called "positionsTmp". Instead add the positions directly to "Positions".

Comment: Yes you're right in BList<Position> is private list List<Position> and positions added to BList really are added to this private list List<Position>. I can't add to BList becasue it implement only IEnumarable.

Comment: I've changed to BList : List<Position> and result is this same.

Comment: I tested your code and it works. The problem must lie somewhere else, outside of the examples you provided.

Comment: Heh yes problem is elsewhere. SI apologize for the problem.